# android databinding error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'

Tags: java, android, data-binding

my partner in ours' project use android databinding.in my pc had error,but in his mac not error.i cant resolve this program.please help!!
it's my build gradle:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

the first build androidstudio say

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:       Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

then i resave XML file use UTF-8.but a new problem birth.like this:

```
:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug
line 1:0 mismatched input '?' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <import type="com.vomoho.vomoho.common.Utils"/>
        <variable name="postDetail" type="com.vomoho.vomoho.entity.PostDetail" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/top"
            layout="@layout/dt_item_postdetail_top"
            bind:postDetail="@{postDetail}"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="@{Utils.getPostType(postDetail.picList) == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
            bind:imageUrl="@{postDetail.picList.size() > 0 ? postDetail.picList.get(0) : ``}"
            bind:width="@{Utils.getPostImgWidth(Utils.getPostType(postDetail.picList))}"
            bind:height="@{Utils.getPostImgHeight(Utils.getPostType(postDetail.picList))}" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            layout="@layout/dt_item_postdetail_bottom"
            bind:postDetail="@{postDetail}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Is that the only thing in your gradle file? Is the dataBinding section within the android{} area? Have you modified your layout file to use the binding syntax yet or have you only added the dataBinding { enabled = true} in it?

Comment: yes，i use databinding synatax in my layout and this code can build in my partner's mac.

Comment: It looks like the problem is the spaces prior to the <?xml

Comment: Or maybe it is saved in a non-UTF-8 character set, even though the XML is telling it that the character set is UTF-8? There are no special characters in the layout as far as I can tell. If you have a way on Windows to look at the characters of the layout file and ensure they are are UTF-8, that would help (od -c on *nix or od /c with windows tools), that could point to a problem.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem, and I finally found the solution.
I found that there is a layout xml file was written like that:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text='@{"年龄 " + String.valueOf(user.age)}'/>
```

and then it cannot built on Windows platform, but it can built on Mac OS X platform, I think its a bug of Android Data Binding, so my temporary solution is:
don't writing any character in `@{}` section, use string reference instead. (in my case, its replace as `android:text='@{ @string/age_text + String.valueOf(user.age) }'/>`)
hope it helps you.

Comment: I also and an arror in layout file.

Comment: I also faced this similar issue. In Linux OS, it works fine. But in Windows it creates problems.

Answer (score 3):

Suffered the same problem for one day, finally found out the root cause. Andoid gradle plugin does not handle the encoding with Byte order mark (BOM) well. It is a encoding reading problem. 
If the file is saved in UTF-8 BOM format, Android gradle tool will detect the encoding as “UTF-8” with UniversalDetector library. The class `android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser` will read like this:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fin, “UTF-8”);
```

The first character returned by `reader.read()` is `0xfeff`. Yes it is the **‘?’** in error message `line 1:0 mismatched input '?' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}`.

Refer the magic number of BOM at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

How UniversalDetector works at http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-it-works.html

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: First, you need to find out which XML file begins with 0xfeff. I suggest you write a tool to read the first bye to find out the files. And then save it again with encoding UTF-8 rather than UTF-8 with BOM. I did this with Sublime Text.

Comment: I suffered this problem after enabling databinding on a large existing project, with approx 100 layout files. To solve the problem I manually went to each file in AS and looked at whether the File/Remove BOM option was enabled (indicating the presence of a BOM character in the file). When it was enabled, I removed the BOM. Found about 20 old layout files which had this BOM mark. Once these were removed, the databinding-enabled build worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error. In my case I there was a redundant xml header at the bottom of a layout file.

Try removing the whitespace (or removing the header), changing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same kind of problem with this log:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input '' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}
```

This was super strange to me, no real feedback. To solve it:

1. Created new layout resource files
2. Copy and  paste the content of the original ones leaving out just the first character
3. Adding it myself in the new file.

Comment: i have the same issue with a project , that don't contain any data binding layout except the declaration in gradle. i ve cleaned all xml files and encoded them in UTF-8 without BOM , but even that still have an exception in LayoutParsing task without any relevant message just a NullPointerException.... very sad that we can't resolve such as error and google don't provide more verbosity in there pluging....

Answer (score 0):

Same situation! My colleagues have no troubles with project on Linux and Mac, but I couldn't built it on Windows.

Finally after 3 days trying to localise exception, I've found 2 layouts causes an error.

In my case trouble was with big cyrillic symbol "И" in `android:text` attribute databinding layout.

Comment: Yes it's true. Example: `android:text='@{"И"}'`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error :

```
line 1:0 mismatched input '?' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}
```

And, I solved it by removing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

this line from the top of my xml file.

Please note that I'm using viewBinding not dataBinding

```
 buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
```