# I am configing data binding in build.gradle, and encountered an eception

Tags: android

I am configing data binding in my project. When I sync project with gradle files, an exception occurs. Has anyone ever had this problem?

Error:Execution failed for task `:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.java.lang.NullPointerException`

(no error message)

the build.gradle

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding{
        enabled true
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix you just need to change `enabled true` to `enabled = true`

e.g:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I refered to this link [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097445/android-databinding-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdatabindingprocesslayo).It seems to be the problem of encoding