# java.lang.NullPointerException when dataBinding enabled = true

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx

Whenever I enable this in my app gradle

```
dataBinding { 
    enabled = true
}
```

and then sync -> It completely succeed.

but when I "run" it, It builds fail and shows this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseOriginalXml(LayoutFileParser.java:135)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseXml(LayoutFileParser.java:93)
>   ...

my app has little amount of Kotlin code, and android version is 3.5, minSdkVersion 19, targetSdkVersion 28, and upgraded to androidX

How can I solve this? which part should I search for solve this problem???

except above code, every thing works perfect.

---

**Edit**
And when I rolled back my code before upgrading to androidX and compiled it, it also shows "Null point exception" and at this time, there are no extra message without just "Null point exception".

---

Comment: hi @youngwoon the one reason i can suspect is it is because of androidx. since sometimes it is not able to process or convert the layout files properly. and at runtime it will crash as the class won't be found. also at compile time it can throw some errors. will you please check and post your most recent layout file for unconverted androidx packages.

Comment: @vikaskumar thank you for your comment!! I can you explain about "post your most recent layout file for unconverted androidx packages"? I can't understand what you want.. sorry for being unfamiliar in English.T_T

Comment: @youngwoon this question cannot be answered unless you provide all the information... alike the XML file which causes the stack-trace above. you've only shown us the result so far.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thank you, how can I know which xml file has caused this error?! There are no such information in above error message. and I can't even imagine which xml would be caused because all xml files works fine unless I put dataBinding{enabled = true}

Comment: @youngwoon sadly the error message does not tell that. it might be, that not a single one of them has `<layout>` and `<data>` nodes added, or the layouts may still reference `com.android.support` libraries instead of `androidx` libraries (these are not automatically migrated).

Comment: @MartinZeitler OMG, I didn't edit any codes but adding dataBinding{~} in gradle. and what's the meaning of that "layouts may still reference android.support libraries"? how can layout reference android x??

Comment: okay do one thing just try searching by pressing command + shift + f and type android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout and see if there are any packages which are still on old packages names even after converting them to androidx. and like so try for recyclerview and cardview and progressbar also with full package names and see them if they are containing androidx or not. i hope this may help, let me know after this.

Comment: @vikaskumar Thank you for trying to help me! as I updated the question, it wasn't because of androidX. I added my answer below!! thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got answer. (cc. [android databinding error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097445/android-databinding-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdatabindingprocesslayo))

I guessed it was because of BOM. Someone said it will happen when the code is used in two different circumstances(Window and Mac).

So in 'res' folder, I clicked 'remove BOM' button in android studio and that action changed some xml files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But it wasn't worked in Mac. This solution worked only in Window.

Comment: this solution worked for me on my Mac. See my answer in the linked SO post above

Comment: I meant the answer by Yanwen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097445/android-databinding-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdatabindingprocesslayo worked for me ie removing the BOM on layout files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a little too much but I figured it out. I created the project on the Mac computer and it wasn't a problem when I switched to windows later. When I tried to create a new file, I got this error and just understood why. Every time I right-clicked on the file I just added, I saw an option called "remove BOM". Clicking this solved my problem. But I did not find the solution to the problem logically, I just found it random.

ex: https://prnt.sc/riw6ex